# Toggle window.location in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

What I am trying to achieve is that whenever you click an image, it changes the window.location url, toggling it between `'#'` and `'#footer'`. Right now, all I have is this:

```
<script>
function clickarrow(){

    var rd=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)

    if (rd > 5){
        window.location="#footer";      
        }

    else{
        window.location="#";
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, this makes a 50:50 chance of either change being made. It works as a temparary fix, but sometimes you have to click up to 6 times for it to take effect.

Is there a way of doing this that properly toggles the `window.location`?

I am using jQuery 1.9.

Comment: or `window.location.hash` ?

Comment: Do you really want a random toggle? It sounds more like your goal is to toggle it *deterministically* rather than probabilistically. If so, you might like my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to reliably toggle the hash, rather than using a random chance, try something like this:

```
function clickarrow(){
    var showFooter = true;

    return function () {
        if (showFooter) {
            window.location.hash = "footer";
        } else {
            window.location.hash = "";
        }

        showFooter = !showFooter;
    }
}

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#myToggleLink').click(clickarrow());
});
```

Note: Normally when binding events, a function reference must be passed in. Here, I'm invoking `clickarrow()` since it returns a function by design. The returned function encapsulates the toggle variable via closure.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks for the answer! I will accept this as soon as I can :)

Comment: Nice usage of closures. @william44isme , note how he is passing a function call that returns a function to the click handler. That way showFooter's value is visible to the handler but hidden from elsewhere. Make sure you understand this, it's an important ability of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum. One of my favorite things about this is that the handler creator (`clickarrow` itself, rather than the function it returns) can be invoked multiple times and a different variable state will be maintained by each handler, which can be useful in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

you can use data attribute to tell what is next step:

```
$('#arrow').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('footer'))
    {
        window.location="#footer"; 
        $(this).data('footer', 'false');
        alert('b');
    }
    else
    {
        window.location="#";
        $(this).data('footer', 'true');
        alert('a');
    }
});
```